# Quiero deployar mi proyecto en vercel, y al deployar me tira este error desde vercel que me inpide subir

Tags: reactjs, vercel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Cloning github.com/CruzGuillermo/Pi-Dogs-Henry (Branch: main, Commit: 31d5293)
Previous build cache not available
Cloning completed: 2.383s
Running "vercel build"
Vercel CLI 28.5.6
Installing dependencies...
yarn install v1.22.17
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...

Comment: Parece ser un bug de Vercel, estás usando la node versión 17? Si es así, esa podría ser la razón... https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/31033

Comment: tengo la version 16.15.1 de node